# Deploy docker container from external registry to Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I got project repository hosted on gitlab. I am using gitlab-ci to build docker container from my project. What I would like to achieve is deploying that container to heroku.

I was trying to follow solution from this question: [How to build, test and deploy using Jhipster, Docker, Gitlab and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011705/how-to-build-test-and-deploy-using-jhipster-docker-gitlab-and-heroku)

Here is how my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` looks like:

```
stages:
 - build
 - package
 - deploy

build_npm:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
  - npm install
  - npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

build_image:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest


deploy_to_heroku:
  stage: deploy
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - docker run registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app= myApp --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
```

What I am trying to achieve is, have 3 stages:

- build: at this moment, compile only npm project (in the future, I
  want to add some `jar` here)
- package: create and push to registry docker image.
- deploy: install docker image on heroku.

I am running into issues with the last stage (`deploy`). To be honest I am not really sure, what should be done here.

I tried to use dpl, regarding to this tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-ruby-application-to-heroku.html

Unfornatelly I am running into issues when trying to run docker image

```
$ docker run registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
/bin/bash: line 49: docker: command not found
```

I am completely blind here. I would really appreciate any solutions, links to articles/tutorials etc.

Comment: doest the "build_image" work for you and resulting in having a fresh image in your Gitlab Registry?

Comment: @DavidSteiman: Yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are starting the app for some reason (using `docker run`) you might don't need. The `dpl` tool is intended to be used inside a codebase, rather than for image deployment. As you said

```
build_image:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
```

is working, what means your runner is able to run docker in docker and successfully pushing images. For heroku deployment, you must only push that image to the heroku docker registry, according to [the official heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). In short you do a

```
deploy_to_heroku:
  stage: deploy
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login --email=_ --username=_ --password=<YOUR-HEROKU-AUTH-TOKEN> registry.heroku.com
    - docker tag registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest registry.heroku.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
    - docker push registry.heroku.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
```

with your heroku auth token, which you can get by `heroku auth:token`

As said in the documentation, pushing to herokus registry triggers a release process of the app.

Comment: Hi I have tried this but I keep getting the following error: 

Error response from daemon: No such image: registry.gitlab.com/username/image:tag

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should point your configuration to your actual container registry. Currently you use the default value, what obviously points to an non existing image

Comment: Another thing to note is that the Heroku registry path is `registry.heroku.com/{app-name}/{process-type}` which you can use with `docker push` -or- you can use the Heroku CLI tool like `heroku container:push {process-type}`

They've also recently changed the container deploy methods so that there's another step involved to release once you've pushed an image.

`heroku container:release {process-type}` 

[Heroku - Building and Pushing Images](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s)

Answer (score 8):

The reason for

> "No such image: registry.gitlab.com/username/image:tag"

error is that tag source should be pulled beforehand. script block should include a `docker pull` statement. The overall script block should be as follows:

```
  script:
    - docker login --email=_ --username=_ --password=<YOUR-HEROKU-AUTH-TOKEN> registry.heroku.com
    - docker pull registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
    - docker tag registry.gitlab.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest registry.heroku.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
    - docker push registry.heroku.com/maciejsobala/myApp:latest
```

Still this is not enough. Heroku changed its release policy so that pushing to Heroku Container Registry does not trigger a release anymore. Here is the extra command to fulfill the missing release task:

```
    - docker run --rm -e HEROKU_API_KEY=<YOUR-HEROKU-AUTH-TOKEN> wingrunr21/alpine-heroku-cli container:release web --app myApp
```